# Como saber se um elemento tem a propriedade html ou value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tenho dois elementos que precisam ser atualizados um DIV e outro INPUT

Um tem deve ser atualizado o value e outro o html, exemplo

```
...
    $.each(json, function (index, value) {
       if (typeof $("#" + index).val() !== "undefined") {
           $("#" + index).val(value);
       } else {
           if (typeof $("#" + index).html() !== "undefined") {
               $("#" + index).html(value);
           }
      }
   });
...
```

Estou fazendo da forma acima mas não esta funcionando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode verificar pelo nome da tag:

```
...
    $.each(json, function (index, value) {
       if ( $("#" + index).prop("tagName") == "INPUT") {
           $("#" + index).val(value);
       } else {
           $("#" + index).html(value);
      }
   });
...
```

Só não ficou claro o motivo desse outro `if` dentro do `else`. Mas desta forma verificando nome da tag já resolve se vai usar `.val()` ou `.html()`.

Comment: Como não tinha certeza de que pudesse gerar erro resolvi colocar outro if, vou usar seu exemplo

Comment: Blz. Dá um feedback se resolveu ou não.

Comment: DVD deu certo, valeu